# magento 2 UpgradeSchema not working

Tags: magento2, setup-upgrade, upgradeschema

I have already created a table with name **tutorial_simplenews**.I want to add new column to that table.my code is below.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Tutorial\SimpleNews\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.0') < 0) {
            $connection = $setup->getConnection();

            $connection->addColumn(
              $setup->getTable('tutorial_simplenews'),
            'test',
            ['type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INT,
            'length' => '11',
           'nullable' => false,
         'default' => '0',
           'comment' => 'Jute Is Allow Status']);





        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

**module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../htdocs/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
     <module name="Tutorial_SimpleNews" setup_version="1.0.0" schema_version="1.0.0">

    </module>
</config>
```

Please can you any one help me, where am i doing wrong in above code.Any references or suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Add your module.xml file code.

Comment: i have added please check @SHPatel

Comment: Any Entry generated in your table? test field is inserted?

Comment: Check setup_module table,  module entry added or not?

Comment: Entry added @SHPatel

Comment: not generated @RakeshJesadiya

Comment: Delete it from setup_module table and run your setup.

Comment: i have deleted and run.but not added column

Answer (score 0):

**Set 1.0.1 setup version in your module.xml file,**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Tutorial_SimpleNews" setup_version="1.0.1" schema_version="1.0.1">      
    </module>
</config>
```

**Now your upgradeschema.php file,**

```
 <?php
    namespace Tutorial\SimpleNews\Setup;
    
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
    
    /**
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
    {
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
        {        
            $installer = $setup;
            $installer->startSetup();
            if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1') < 0) {
                $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
                    $installer->getTable('tutorial_simplenews'),
                    'test',
                    [
                        'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INT,
                        'nullable' => true,
                        'length' => '11',                    
                        'default' => '0',
                        'comment' => 'Jute Is Allow Status'
                    ]
                );
            }
            $installer->endSetup();
        }
    }
```

Run below commands
`php bin/magento cache:clean`  and
`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Comment: Please let me know if you have issue